# jQuery Tablesorter - custom parser not working

Tags: jquery, parsing, tablesorter

I'm trying to write a custom parser for the jQuery plugin, [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/). The idea is for it to sort the numbers in descending order on the first click.

However, when I sort the table, the order doesn't change. Sometimes a few rows move, but most of them stay the same. Here is the code:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'desc',
    is: function(s) { return false },
    format: function(s) {
        return 1.0 / parseFloat( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

The other parsers I've written are working fine. I tried 9999 minus the number instead of 1.0 divided by it, in case it was a problem with floats (no luck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I had some empty cells in each column, which were being parsed as "NaN". Why this screwed up the ordering, I don't know (blank cells were intermittently spaced with regular numbers, there was no order to anything).

In short, this code works for the format function:

```
 format: function(s) {
  if ( s == '' )
   return 0;  
  return -parseInt( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
 }
```

Comment: Good catch with the empty fields.  Didn't even consider that possibility reading your OP.

Answer (score 0):

To sort something in reverse numeric order, to me the natural way to go is to multiply it by -1, rather than the methods you've tried.

As to the parser itself, the only difference I notice is that you are returning an actual number, whereas the [parser example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) at the Tablesorter site returns a string.  Perhaps converting the value back to string before returning it would work?

Comment: Isn't it returning a number? `replace(/bad/,0)` would return 0, rather than "0", right?

Comment: No, `replace` always returns a string.  You need to use parseInt, as you did in the solution that you posted a moment ago.